# Quickly get to the first page of a tabbed app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, tabs

Is there a way to quickly get to the first page of a tabbed app? For instance, the Home screen is an example of a tabbed "app", with the dots at the bottom. Except, to get to the first page, you of course just hit the Home screen. But in other apps, you can't do that.

So, is it possible to do so, or is the only way to do this is to swipe all the way Left until you get to the start?

I've seen in some apps, like Instapaper, where you can actually press and hold on the dots indicating what page you're on, then drag to the page you want to be on. But I'm guessing that that's the huge exception and not the rule.

Comment: In the case of the Home screen, you can also "tap" in the area to the left/right of the dots to change "tabs" in the respective direction (the dots themselves don't appear to be tappable). Perhaps marginally quicker than swiping; maybe not?